# Verilog: bit slice vector twice

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose we have a 128 bit reg:

```
reg [127:0] line;
```

And we first select a 32-bit word out of it, and then select byte from this word, all using slicing:

```
word = line[(127-32*byte_addr[3:2])-:32];
byte = word[7:0];
```

That works fine. But if I wan't to combine both operators, in same line, it seems it is not permitted.

```
mybyte = line[(127-32*byte_addr[3:2])-:32][7:0]; //all the hell breaks loose
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a clear rule in SV 3.1a spec that forbids this.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Which tools are you using?

Comment: "Syntax error. Token is '['" VCS.

Comment: Error is correct. Since `line` is declared as a one-dimensional array, you can only use a single index selector on it.

Comment: isn't a result of a slice a vector, which can also be sliced? So, basically, slice operator does not compose and line[][] is interpreted as multidimensional access, which produces an error?

Comment: The SystemVerilog 3.1a spec is obsolete. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete your SystemVerilog 3.1a spec and get a [free copy of the 1800-2012 LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

The concatenation operator described in section 11.4.12 does what you want.

```
mybyte = {line[(127-32*byte_addr[3:2])-:32]}[7:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1800-2012 LRM says (7.4.6)

> An expression can select part of a packed array, or any integer type,
>   which is assumed to be numbered down to 0.
>   The term part-select refers
>   to a selection of one or more contiguous bits of a single-dimension
>   packed array.

No mention of a part-select of a part-select, which is what you are trying to do.

Can you make `line` multidimensional? Something like

```
reg [3:0][7:0] line [3:0];
```

This would make the indexing trivial.

Comment: thanks for the spec reference. no, unfortunately in this case I can't. Or is there a way to "unslice"/pack that multidimensional array into 128 bit reg?